# How can I get a script's output to be copied to the Windows clipboard?

Tags: windows, perl, scripting, batch-file, clipboard

I find myself running scripts and copy-pasting the output of these runs into emails or into some other documents. Is there a way such that I can make the copy-to-clipboard step a part of the script itself? Most of my scripts are either Perl or bat files and I work on Windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [utility called clip.exe](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/copy-dos-command-line-output-clipboard-clip-exe/2506/) that you can use. Just pipe the output of your script or any other command into clip.exe (First, put it on your path somewhere. If you don't have a usual place for these kindss of utilities, you can dump it in the directory you usually run your scripts from, or I've known people to use `c:\Windows\system32` in a pinch...):

```
somescript.bat | clip
```

Then paste away.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, install and use [Win32::Clipboard](http://www.xav.com/perl/site/lib/Win32/Clipboard.html) module

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the clipboard but you can pipe the output to a text file but doing something like this:

```
somescript.bat > output.txt
```

Comment: Sure, but unfortunately is not what we were looking for :(