# How to make an ruby output to copy itself - clipboard

Tags: ruby, batch-file, clipboard

Would someone please help me with this. I need the ruby output to be directly copied to clipboard.

I recently discovered [GeoIPGen](http://www.morningstarsecurity.com/research/geoipgen) and it is awesome. I made a .bat script that runs GeoIPGen through which it generates a random IP but I need to make it to copy itself to clipboard.

Can you help me with this one?
Thanks in advance!

.BAT SCRIPT CODE EXAMPLE

```
C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe C:\geo\geoipgen -n 1 US
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [gem called clipboard](https://github.com/janlelis/clipboard) that provides the capability to store data in the system clipboard programmatically.

Comment: Would you please write an more in-depth explanation how to use this type of gem as I am really new to this field and I do not know relatively nothing about Ruby. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a soulution since I am using Command Prompt:

[HowToGeek Tutorial - How to copy output text from the command line to the windows clipboard](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28473/how-to-copy-output-text-from-the-command-line-to-the-windows-clipboard/)

[How can I get a script's output to be copied to the Windows clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307658/how-can-i-get-a-scripts-output-to-be-copied-to-the-windows-clipboard?rq=1)